# How to select values from html using css selector where there is only class and style attributesthis class is genric (mean used some where else also)

Tags: java, html, selenium, web-scraping

'''

29/11/2021
                
'''
 I am using List e3 = driver1.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.border")); which gives me date but some other values also

I want to extract this date without using ID because there are many dates with different ID where iteration will not be possible.

so I need to select any other values so that I can extract all the dates present in that table

this is a website link :- https://www.mia.org.my/v2/surveillance/disciplinary/decisions.aspx

Comment: <td class="border" style="width: 95px; user-select: auto;">
                    <span id="PageContents_LVDecisions_ctrl1_Label2_1" style="user-select: auto;">29/11/2021</span>
                </td>   this is the code from where i have to take css selector

Answer (score 0):

Css selectors allow selection by partial attribute match (e.g. partial ID match):

[image]

In your example you can see that all dates can be matched with ids containing `PageContents_LVDecision_ctrl`:

```
span[id*='PageContents_LVDecisions_ctrl']
```

Documentation page for `*=` syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax

For more [see this interactive Css selector tester](http://granitosaur.us/xpath-tester/?html=PHRib2R5Pjx0cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCBjbGFzcz0iYm9yZGVyIiBzdHlsZT0id2lkdGg6OTVweCI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsMF9MYWJlbDJfMCI%2BMjkvMTEvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9IndpZHRodGQ3NSBib3JkZXIiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDBfU2VsZWN0XzAiIGhyZWY9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6X19kb1Bvc3RCYWNrKCdjdGwwMCRQYWdlQ29udGVudHMkTFZEZWNpc2lvbnMkY3RybDAkY3RsMDAkU2VsZWN0JywnJykiPkF1Z3VzdGluZSBULksuIEphbWVzICg2MzYwKTwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dHI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9ImJvcmRlciIgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjk1cHgiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDFfTGFiZWwyXzEiPjI5LzExLzIwMjE8L3NwYW4%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%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsMl9MYWJlbDJfMiI%2BMjkvMTEvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%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%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsM19MYWJlbDJfMyI%2BMjIvMDkvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%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%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsNF9MYWJlbDJfNCI%2BMjIvMDkvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9IndpZHRodGQ3NSBib3JkZXIiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDRfU2VsZWN0XzQiIGhyZWY9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6X19kb1Bvc3RCYWNrKCdjdGwwMCRQYWdlQ29udGVudHMkTFZEZWNpc2lvbnMkY3RybDQkY3RsMDAkU2VsZWN0JywnJykiPkxpbSBDaHVuIEhvbmcgKDM4NzAwKTwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dHI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9ImJvcmRlciIgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjk1cHgiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDVfTGFiZWwyXzUiPjIyLzA5LzIwMjE8L3NwYW4%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%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsNl9MYWJlbDJfNiI%2BMjIvMDkvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9IndpZHRodGQ3NSBib3JkZXIiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDZfU2VsZWN0XzYiIGhyZWY9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6X19kb1Bvc3RCYWNrKCdjdGwwMCRQYWdlQ29udGVudHMkTFZEZWNpc2lvbnMkY3RybDYkY3RsMDAkU2VsZWN0JywnJykiPkxvdyBIdWFuIFNlbmcgKDM1NDY1KTwvYT4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dHI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9ImJvcmRlciIgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjk1cHgiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDdfTGFiZWwyXzciPjIyLzA5LzIwMjE8L3NwYW4%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RkPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRkIGNsYXNzPSJ3aWR0aHRkNzUgYm9yZGVyIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8YSBpZD0iUGFnZUNvbnRlbnRzX0xWRGVjaXNpb25zX2N0cmw3X1NlbGVjdF83IiBocmVmPSJqYXZhc2NyaXB0Ol9fZG9Qb3N0QmFjaygnY3RsMDAkUGFnZUNvbnRlbnRzJExWRGVjaXNpb25zJGN0cmw3JGN0bDAwJFNlbGVjdCcsJycpIj5UZWggSGFuIExlaW5nICgzMTgzNCk8L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RkPgogICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRkIGNsYXNzPSJib3JkZXIiIHN0eWxlPSJ3aWR0aDo5NXB4Ij4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8c3BhbiBpZD0iUGFnZUNvbnRlbnRzX0xWRGVjaXNpb25zX2N0cmw4X0xhYmVsMl84Ij4yMi8wOS8yMDIxPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCBjbGFzcz0id2lkdGh0ZDc1IGJvcmRlciI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGEgaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsOF9TZWxlY3RfOCIgaHJlZj0iamF2YXNjcmlwdDpfX2RvUG9zdEJhY2soJ2N0bDAwJFBhZ2VDb250ZW50cyRMVkRlY2lzaW9ucyRjdHJsOCRjdGwwMCRTZWxlY3QnLCcnKSI%2BVGVuIEppYSBTaGVuZyAoNDQ3MjEpPC9hPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4KICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0cj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCBjbGFzcz0iYm9yZGVyIiBzdHlsZT0id2lkdGg6OTVweCI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHNwYW4gaWQ9IlBhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsOV9MYWJlbDJfOSI%2BMjIvMDkvMjAyMTwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgY2xhc3M9IndpZHRodGQ3NSBib3JkZXIiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxhIGlkPSJQYWdlQ29udGVudHNfTFZEZWNpc2lvbnNfY3RybDlfU2VsZWN0XzkiIGhyZWY9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6X19kb1Bvc3RCYWNrKCdjdGwwMCRQYWdlQ29udGVudHMkTFZEZWNpc2lvbnMkY3RybDkkY3RsMDAkU2VsZWN0JywnJykiPlllZSBQdWkgV2FoICgyMTU4NCk8L2E%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RkPgogICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI%2BCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90Ym9keT4%3D&xpath=c3BhbltpZCo9J1BhZ2VDb250ZW50c19MVkRlY2lzaW9uc19jdHJsJ10%3D&css=1#editor)